# Circuit design for switching between two low voltage AC loads

Tags: circuit-design

I've been trying to figure out this circuit for hours and I'm stuck! I have got a working version but it requires 10 switches to be toggled and I need this to be cut down to 2 switches - I think it can be achieved with the use of active components.

**Context**

There are two loads and two AC sources.

When AC1's switch is turned on and AC2's switch is turned off, then load1 should receive a positive fully rectified AC signal.

When AC2's switch is turned on and AC1's switch is turned off, then load2 should receive a negative fully rectified AC signal.

**Requirements**

There can only be 2 wires going to Load 1 & Load 2.

The AC1 switch and AC2 switch must remain.

**Progress**

I have got a working version of the circuit, but it relies on 10 switches. I would like to get rid of all but two switches for AC1 and AC2.

The below circuit diagrams show how the circuit works in both modes (Load 1 or Load 2).

[image: Load1]

[image: Load2]

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use a double pole, double throw switch?

Comment: Do you not simply wire AC1 --> FWB --> Load1 and AC2 --> FWB -- Load2 with one switch each? Why do they have to be commoned? What other switch/voltage/load states are needed?

Comment: If you construct a two input truth table, you will see that it has four possible output states (sets of output conditions), and two of them are undefined in your post - both sources on and both sources off.  Both of the solutions posted at this time make assumptions about those two output states that are not defined in your post, and have significant impact on the solution.

Comment: I should have been clearer - I can only have two wires going to Load 1 and Load 2. That is a critical constraint.

Truth table is as follows: 

AC1 | AC2 | Load1 | Load2
  0   |    0   |    0      |     0   
  1   |    0   |    1      |     0  
  0   |    1   |    0      |     1   
  1   |    1   |  any    |    any

Answer (score 1):

Would this suit your needs?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG8dSJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or this one, with fewer diodes? (SW1 and SW2 can be "ganged" together as a single double-pole-double-throw switch.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJBWB3.png)</sup>

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my original post - there can only be two wires going to Load1 and Load2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that for some reason, there is only one pair of wires between the two sources and the two loads, and that the two sources must share a common connection.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5FhZ9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT:** It seems that this switching must be automatic, based on the presence of V1 and/or V2. Since both loads can't be powered at the same time, this circuit gives priority to V1.

Comment: Not obvious to me.  That state in the (missing) truth table is undefined.  If (1,1) is allowed, the problem reduces to trivial.  If it is a lockout condition, that is a difficult task.  Also, your solution does not allow for the (0,0) condition, both loads unpowered.  To be fain, also undefined by the OP.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. That looks pretty close - but instead of a switch, when V1 is on then R1 should be powered, when V2 is on then R2 should be powered.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Solution # 1:** With three wires to feed the two loads.

Two transformers with centre-tapped secondaries and a three-position, centre-off switch are required.

Here's the schematic.

[image]

With AC2 off and AC1 on, a positive full-wave rectified voltage is fed to Load 1.

Likewise, with AC1 off and AC2 on, a negative full-wave rectified voltage is fed to Load 2.

**Solution # 2:** With only two wires to feed the two loads.

Two DPDT electromagnetic relays and two SPST toggle switches are required.

Here's the schematic.

[image]